# Psycopg2, when im inserting its only inserting one letter

Tags: python, postgresql, flask

I was inserting into my postgres db, and when i insert its only inserting one letter into the database.

```
@app.route("/user/create")
def create_user():
    email = request.headers.get("email")
    password = request.headers.get("password")

    if email is None:
        return {
            "status_code": "400",
            "error": "Email is required"
        }
    
    elif password is None:
        return {
            "status_code": "400",
            "error": "Password is required"
        }
    
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    SQL = "INSERT INTO public.users (email, password, registered_on, admin) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s);"
    val = email, password, datetime.datetime.now(), False,

    try:
        result = cursor.execute(SQL, val)
        connection.commit()
        return {"status_code": "200"}
    except Exception as e:
        return {
            "status_code": "400",
            "error": str(e)
        }
```

this is my code
and the image below is what doing the `SELECT * FROM public.users;` in the table on pgadmin

Comment: What means _one letter_ (one letter per column) ?

Comment: The code looks fine, so if something doesn't work, I would assume the error is in the request. Have you checked whether the "email" and "password" headers contain the correct data?

Comment: Show the output of the select as text(not image) update to question.